# How to log a message to the console in Handlebars?

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm working with Ember.js and wondering if there is a built-in function in Handlebars that allows me to print to the console like `{{ log "my message" }}` similar to what we can currently do with logging objects like: `{{ log this }}`?

---

Or do I have to [define my helper function every time](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/handlebars-js-part-3-tips-and-tricks)?

But that is even not working for me ([click for jsbin](http://jsbin.com/iwiruw/111/edit)):

I have in the HTML Handlebars:

```
{{ debug "this is my string" }}
```

Then in app.js I have:

```
Ember.Handlebars.helper('debug', function(the_string){
    console.log(the_string);
});
```

But app.js is not receiving `the_string`, so `the_string` is undefined there, what's going on?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm not sure why Ember.Handlebars.helper doesn't work... As of now you can try

```
  Ember.Handlebars.registerHelper('debug', function(the_string){
    Ember.Logger.log(the_string);
    // or simply
    console.log(the_string);
  });
```

Comment: Thank you! `registerHelper()` is the function to use instead of `helper()`. How do I know about `registerHelper()` if it's [not even listed in the api](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.html)?

Comment: @HaoQiLi I guess this is the price to pay when you use a very young and rapidly changing **awesome** framework :)

Comment: So Selva Ganesh, how did you know/learn/find out about `registerHelper`?

Comment: Tracking the emberjs issues and commits will help you a lot... Try to go through the source code...All the Embers handlebars helpers uses the registerHelper... https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-handlebars/lib/helpers/unbound.js

Answer (score 5):

Just posting a new answer for people who find this in future. There is an easier way now.

Your `{{debug}}` helper is effectively built-in with the native `{{log}}` helper. You can also add a breakpoint with the `{{debugger}}` helper.

See [the guides](http://guides.emberjs.com/v2.0.0/templates/development-helpers/) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Declare this somewhere in your app:

```
hbs.registerHelper("log", function(data){
  console.log(data)
});
```

usage:
    `{{log data}}`

Comment: this doesn't seem to work for me

Comment: Please share your declarations, version of handlebars and use of snippet.

Comment: it seems i was looking at the wrong console, the one from the browser. it shows up fine in the server's logs/console

Comment: Yeah it happened to me as well.